# Zonal statistics considering the size of the polygons within each raster cel [QGIS]

Tags: qgis, zonal-statistics

When I calculate the zonal statistics the mean the size of the polygon is not considered in calculation. The value of the cel in the top left which is covered by a relatively small polygon is weighted the same as the ones in the bottom of the shape. Is there a way of doing this differently?

[image: raster and polygons]